# Volvo S40 2010 2.0 R d acceleration

Tags: volvo, acceleration, s40

Sometimes it seems for no reason when I accelerate it chokes and strains and won't go far over 2000rpm I've tried dropping it down a gear to clear and I've found when I change up if I let it catch before accelerating this can help it does clear though? Then it runs like a dream ?  Thanks for any help you can give me .Dan

Comment: A damaged catalytic converter may rattle when banged by hand, blocking exhaust flow. Removing the O2 sensor for an alternate exhaust path and short drive with renewed power is another way to determine catcon damage. Loss of fuel pressure can be assessed with a fuel pressure gauge. Replaced fuel filter?

Comment: Any sign of a "Check Engine" light? The behaviour sounds like the ECU has detected a fault and has put the engine into so-called "limp mode" where engine rpm is restricted to mitigate potential damage. Can you get someone with an OBD-II code reader to see if there are any fault codes?

Comment: No lights come up when it happens I'll look into the other suggestions.  Thanks